# Upper case and lower case query filter

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar(40) column that saves an hexadecimal ID, I need that ID in upper case, like *id_xxxx*; where xxxx is an hexadecimal number 0-9 A-F
The first 3 letters must be in lower case.

1) There's a way to get a list of the IDs where the hexadecimal number are not in upper case?

2) There's a way to make the database engine turn a wrong ID like **ID_abc1** into **id_ABC1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn *all* values into the correct case with this expression:

```
concat('id_', upper(substr(myHexId, 4)))
```

See [live demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50df0/1).

To find all hex values that are not in upper case:

```
where substr(myHexId,4) != upper(substr(myHexId,4))
```

to find all incorrectly formatted values (either "id_" or hex not correct):

```
where myHexId != concat('id_', upper(substr(myHexId, 4)))
```

Comment: What happens if there's not a valid HEX number? Can I filter them and get a list?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to find all values that are not in the correct format? Not hex? I've added some options to the answer